# Is LogicalOperationStack incompatible with async in .Net 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, .net-4.5

`Trace.CorrelationManager.LogicalOperationStack` enables having nested logical operation identifiers where the most common case is logging (NDC). Should it still work with `async-await`?

Here's a simple example using `LogicalFlow` which is my simple wrapper over the `LogicalOperationStack`:

```
private static void Main() => OuterOperationAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

private static async Task OuterOperationAsync()
{
    Console.WriteLine(LogicalFlow.CurrentOperationId);
    using (LogicalFlow.StartScope())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\t" + LogicalFlow.CurrentOperationId);
        await InnerOperationAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("\t" + LogicalFlow.CurrentOperationId);
        await InnerOperationAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("\t" + LogicalFlow.CurrentOperationId);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(LogicalFlow.CurrentOperationId);
}

private static async Task InnerOperationAsync()
{
    using (LogicalFlow.StartScope())
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
    }
}
```

`LogicalFlow`:

```
public static class LogicalFlow
{
    public static Guid CurrentOperationId =>
        Trace.CorrelationManager.LogicalOperationStack.Count > 0
            ? (Guid) Trace.CorrelationManager.LogicalOperationStack.Peek()
            : Guid.Empty;

    public static IDisposable StartScope()
    {
        Trace.CorrelationManager.StartLogicalOperation();
        return new Stopper();
    }

    private static void StopScope() => 
        Trace.CorrelationManager.StopLogicalOperation();

    private class Stopper : IDisposable
    {
        private bool _isDisposed;
        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (!_isDisposed)
            {
                StopScope();
                _isDisposed = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
    49985135-1e39-404c-834a-9f12026d9b65
    54674452-e1c5-4b1b-91ed-6bd6ea725b98
    c6ec00fd-bff8-4bde-bf70-e073b6714ae5
54674452-e1c5-4b1b-91ed-6bd6ea725b98
```

The specific values don't really matter, but as I understand it both the outer lines should show `Guid.Empty` (i.e. `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`) and the inner lines should show the same `Guid` value.

You might say that `LogicalOperationStack` is using a `Stack` which is not thread-safe and that's why the output is wrong. But while that's true in general, in this case **there's never more than a single thread accessing the `LogicalOperationStack` at the same time** (every `async` operation is awaited when called and no use of combinators such as `Task.WhenAll`)

The issue is that `LogicalOperationStack` is stored in the `CallContext` which has a copy-on-write behavior. That means that as long as you don't explicitly set something in the `CallContext` (and you don't when you add to an existing stack with `StartLogicalOperation`) you're using the parent context and not your own.

This can be shown by simply setting **anything** into the `CallContext` before adding to the existing stack. For example if we changed `StartScope` to this:

```
public static IDisposable StartScope()
{
    CallContext.LogicalSetData("Bar", "Arnon");
    Trace.CorrelationManager.StartLogicalOperation();
    return new Stopper();
}
```

The output is:

```
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
    fdc22318-53ef-4ae5-83ff-6c3e3864e37a
    fdc22318-53ef-4ae5-83ff-6c3e3864e37a
    fdc22318-53ef-4ae5-83ff-6c3e3864e37a
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

Note: *I'm not suggesting anyone actually do this. The real practical solution would be to use an `ImmutableStack` instead of the `LogicalOperationStack` as it's both thread-safe and since it's immutable when you call `Pop` you get back a new `ImmutableStack` that you then need to set back into the `CallContext`. A full implementation is available as an answer to this question: [Tracking c#/.NET tasks flow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24468894/885318)*

So, should `LogicalOperationStack` work with `async` and it's just a bug? Is `LogicalOperationStack` just not meant for the `async` world? Or am I missing something?

---

**Update**: Using `Task.Delay` is apparently confusing as it uses `System.Threading.Timer` which [captures the `ExecutionContext` internally](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/timer.cs,544). Using `await Task.Yield();` instead of `await Task.Delay(100);` makes the example easier to understand.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate: [Is CorrelationManager.LogicalOperationStack compatible with Parallel.For, Tasks, Threads, etc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729479/is-correlationmanager-logicaloperationstack-compatible-with-parallel-for-tasks)

Comment: @Noseratio nope. That's not about `async-await` but about a bug that was already fixed.

Comment: Agreed, not a dupe. Did you check if it works as expected on the same thread, e.g. if you replace  `await Task.Delay(100)` with `Task.Delay(100).Wait()`?

Comment: @Noseratio yes. It works of course, because there's only a single thread (and so a single `CallContext`). It's as if the method wasn't `async` to begin with.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. [Here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/remoting/callcontext.cs,f0df09325f655c90,references) it gets merged only if it has new user data (`lc.HasUserData`) on `LogicalCallContext` itself (as you code shows), but not on the `s_CorrelationMgrSlotName` child slot, which is itself a dictiionary.

Comment: @Noseratio I think that's irrelevant. AFAIK `LogicalCallContext` is used to transfer `CallContext` items to different `AppDomain`s. `Merge` is only used by `RealProxy` which is the class behind remoting and WCF.

Comment: Note sure about `Merge` itself, but `LogicalCallContext` is used inside `ExecutionContext` to flow data set with `CallContext.LogicalSetData`, [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/remoting/callcontext.cs,946b188eee23f5b9,references). That's how `LogicalSetData/LogicalGetData` gets flowed across async calls within the same appdomain, too.

Comment: Overall, I think the design of `ExecutionContext` flow (including its one-level-only copy-on-write logic) is a bit twisted. E.g., they don't have a public API to suppress `SynchronizationContext` flow when you use `ExecutionContext.Capture`/`Run`, which is a problem when implementing `ICriticalNotifyCompletion`.

Comment: @downvoter something wrong?

Comment: It's a great technical question. Perhaps, the downvoter simply doesn't understand what it's all about.

Comment: Related blog post by Stephen Cleary, explaining the issue with mutable data in the logical call context: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, `LogicalOperationStack` *should* work with `async-await` and *it is* a bug that it doesn't.

I've contacted the relevant developer at Microsoft and his response was this:

> "**I wasn't aware of this, but it does seem broken**. The copy-on-write logic is supposed to behave exactly as if we'd really created a copy of the `ExecutionContext` on entry into the method.  However, copying the `ExecutionContext` would have created a deep copy of the `CorrelationManager` context, as it's special-cased in `CallContext.Clone()`.  We don't take that into account in the copy-on-write logic."

Moreover, he recommended using the new [`System.Threading.AsyncLocal<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn906268%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class added in .Net 4.6 instead which should handle that issue correctly.

So, I went ahead and implemented `LogicalFlow` on top of an `AsyncLocal` instead of the `LogicalOperationStack` using VS2015 RC and .Net 4.6:

```
public static class LogicalFlow
{
    private static AsyncLocal<Stack> _asyncLogicalOperationStack = new AsyncLocal<Stack>();

    private static Stack AsyncLogicalOperationStack
    {
        get
        {
            if (_asyncLogicalOperationStack.Value == null)
            {
                _asyncLogicalOperationStack.Value = new Stack();
            }

            return _asyncLogicalOperationStack.Value;
        }
    }

    public static Guid CurrentOperationId =>
        AsyncLogicalOperationStack.Count > 0
            ? (Guid)AsyncLogicalOperationStack.Peek()
            : Guid.Empty;

    public static IDisposable StartScope()
    {
        AsyncLogicalOperationStack.Push(Guid.NewGuid());
        return new Stopper();
    }

    private static void StopScope() =>
        AsyncLogicalOperationStack.Pop();
}
```

And the output for the same test is indeed as it should be:

```
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
    ae90c3e3-c801-4bc8-bc34-9bccfc2b692a
    ae90c3e3-c801-4bc8-bc34-9bccfc2b692a
    ae90c3e3-c801-4bc8-bc34-9bccfc2b692a
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

Comment: I'm curious, how did you contact the relevant developer at Microsoft? [The bug at Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1114703/logicaloperationstack-doesnt-work-with-async) doesn't have any feedback from Microsoft yet.

Comment: Is there any way AsyncLocal behavior can be achieved in .net 4.5?

Comment: @FilipStas maybe, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: @i3arnon I think there may be a problem with this code, say you created scope on a main thread and stopped it, then you try to create a new scope from the inside of a method running in QueueUserWorkItem, AsyncLogicalOperationStack getter will return _asyncLogicalOperationStack.Value since it was initialized previously, but .Value will be null. I can repro this behavior in windows service trying to start scope in OnStart after creating/stopping at least 1 scope in constructor

Comment: @taras.roshko true, because I created the AsyncLocal once and set it's value once when I need to set it for each async flow separately. I updated the answer accordingly

Comment: @i3arnon Will your `LogicalFlow` class behave properly in a scenario when several parallel tasks are started in a child operation and are creating their own child operations? In other words, is this class thread safe?

Comment: I don't believe this solution is good enough. Like you said in a comment below, deep cloning is required otherwise several threads end up with the same (non-thread-safe stack). If I do something like `using (LogicalFlow.StartScope()) { Task.WaitAll(Task.Run(InnerOperationAsync), Task.Run(InnerOperationAsync)) }`, all 3 threads (parent and two children) will have the same `Stack` instance (as I verified with `Object.ReferenceEquals`) . What you did here however should work fine as it utilizes deep copying: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24468972/67824.

Comment: I have to deplore the lack of proactivity from Microsoft: they answered privately to a person who raised the bug, but they didn't update their documentation!

Answer (score 6):

If you're still interested in this, I believe it's a bug in how they flow `LogicalOperationStack` and I think it's a good idea to report it.

They give special treatment to `LogicalOperationStack`'s stack [here in     `LogicalCallContext.Clone`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/remoting/callcontext.cs,faffee3783da8754,references), by doing a deep copy (unlike with other data stored via `CallContext.LogicalSetData/LogicalGetData`, on which only a shallow copy is performed).

This `LogicalCallContext.Clone` is called every time `ExecutionContext.CreateCopy` or  `ExecutionContext.CreateMutableCopy` is called to flow the `ExecutionContext`.

Based on your code, I did a little experiment by providing my own mutable stack for `"System.Diagnostics.Trace.CorrelationManagerSlot"` slot in `LogicalCallContext`, to see when and how many times it actually gets cloned.

The code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static readonly string CorrelationManagerSlot = "System.Diagnostics.Trace.CorrelationManagerSlot";

        public static void ShowCorrelationManagerStack(object where)
        {
            object top = "null";
            var stack = (MyStack)CallContext.LogicalGetData(CorrelationManagerSlot);
            if (stack.Count > 0)
                top = stack.Peek();

            Console.WriteLine("{0}: MyStack Id={1}, Count={2}, on thread {3}, top: {4}",
                where, stack.Id, stack.Count, Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId, top);
        }

        private static void Main()
        {
            CallContext.LogicalSetData(CorrelationManagerSlot, new MyStack());

            OuterOperationAsync().Wait();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static async Task OuterOperationAsync()
        {
            ShowCorrelationManagerStack(1.1);

            using (LogicalFlow.StartScope())
            {
                ShowCorrelationManagerStack(1.2);
                Console.WriteLine("\t" + LogicalFlow.CurrentOperationId);
                await InnerOperationAsync();
                ShowCorrelationManagerStack(1.3);
                Console.WriteLine("\t" + LogicalFlow.CurrentOperationId);
                await InnerOperationAsync();
                ShowCorrelationManagerStack(1.4);
                Console.WriteLine("\t" + LogicalFlow.CurrentOperationId);
            }

            ShowCorrelationManagerStack(1.5);
        }

        private static async Task InnerOperationAsync()
        {
            ShowCorrelationManagerStack(2.1);
            using (LogicalFlow.StartScope())
            {
                ShowCorrelationManagerStack(2.2);
                await Task.Delay(100);
                ShowCorrelationManagerStack(2.3);
            }
            ShowCorrelationManagerStack(2.4);
        }
    }

    public class MyStack : Stack, ICloneable
    {
        public static int s_Id = 0;

        public int Id { get; private set; }

        object ICloneable.Clone()
        {
            var cloneId = Interlocked.Increment(ref s_Id); ;
            Console.WriteLine("Cloning MyStack Id={0} into {1} on thread {2}", this.Id, cloneId, Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId);

            var clone = new MyStack();
            clone.Id = cloneId;

            foreach (var item in this.ToArray().Reverse())
                clone.Push(item);

            return clone;
        }
    }

    public static class LogicalFlow
    {
        public static Guid CurrentOperationId
        {
            get
            {
                return Trace.CorrelationManager.LogicalOperationStack.Count > 0
                    ? (Guid)Trace.CorrelationManager.LogicalOperationStack.Peek()
                    : Guid.Empty;
            }
        }

        public static IDisposable StartScope()
        {
            Program.ShowCorrelationManagerStack("Before StartLogicalOperation");
            Trace.CorrelationManager.StartLogicalOperation();
            Program.ShowCorrelationManagerStack("After StartLogicalOperation");
            return new Stopper();
        }

        private static void StopScope()
        {
            Program.ShowCorrelationManagerStack("Before StopLogicalOperation");
            Trace.CorrelationManager.StopLogicalOperation();
            Program.ShowCorrelationManagerStack("After StopLogicalOperation");
        }

        private class Stopper : IDisposable
        {
            private bool _isDisposed;
            public void Dispose()
            {
                if (!_isDisposed)
                {
                    StopScope();
                    _isDisposed = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result is quite surprising. Even though there're only two threads involved in this async workflow, the stack gets cloned as many as 4 times. And the problem is, the matching `Stack.Push` and `Stack.Pop` operations (called by `StartLogicalOperation`/`StopLogicalOperation`) operate on the different, non-matching clones of the stack, thus disbalancing the "logical" stack. That's where the bug lays in.

This indeed makes `LogicalOperationStack` totally unusable across async calls, even though there's no concurrent forks of tasks.

**Updated**, I also did a little research about how it may behave for synchronous calls, to address [these comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28769483/is-logicaloperationstack-incompatible-with-async-in-net-4-5/28869819#comment45826644_28769483):

> Agreed, not a dupe. Did you check if it works as expected on the same
>   thread, e.g. if you replace await Task.Delay(100) with
>   Task.Delay(100).Wait()? –  Noseratio Feb 27 at 21:00
>
> @Noseratio yes. It works of course, because there's only a single thread (and so a single CallContext). It's as if the method wasn't
>   async to begin with. –  i3arnon Feb 27 at 21:01

Single thread doesn't mean single `CallContext`. Even for synchronous continuations on the same single thread the execution context (and its inner `LogicalCallContext`) can get cloned. Example, using the above code:

```
private static void Main()
{
    CallContext.LogicalSetData(CorrelationManagerSlot, new MyStack());

    ShowCorrelationManagerStack(0.1);

    CallContext.LogicalSetData("slot1", "value1");
    Console.WriteLine(CallContext.LogicalGetData("slot1"));

    Task.FromResult(0).ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            ShowCorrelationManagerStack(0.2);

            CallContext.LogicalSetData("slot1", "value2");
            Console.WriteLine(CallContext.LogicalGetData("slot1"));
        }, 
        CancellationToken.None,
        TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously,
        TaskScheduler.Default);

    ShowCorrelationManagerStack(0.3);
    Console.WriteLine(CallContext.LogicalGetData("slot1"));

    // ...
}
```

Output (note how we lose `"value2"`):

```
0.1: MyStack Id=0, Count=0, on thread 9, top:
value1
Cloning MyStack Id=0 into 1 on thread 9
0.2: MyStack Id=1, Count=0, on thread 9, top:
value2
0.3: MyStack Id=0, Count=0, on thread 9, top:
value1
```

Comment: `Task.Delay` captures the `ExecutionContext` internally so it's not a surprise you have 4 clones. You can use `Task.Yield` to make it simpler to understand. With `Task.Yield` you only get the expected 2 clones. The issue, as I described, is that because of the "copy-on-write" behavior you use the parent context when you shouldn't. In your example it manifests as the 2 clones are cloned from the same original stack.

Comment: About your update: I didn't state that the stack won't get cloned with `Task.Delay(100).Wait()` (actually, it does get cloned in this case, it doesn't with `Task.Yield.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` though). I've stated that it works as expected as the cloned stack isn't used by the single thread that's running the code (just like your `"value2"`)

Comment: Also, your `MyStack.Clone` doesn't clone the stack correctly as it reverses it each time.

Comment: @i3arnon, there's indeed a bug which can be fixed as `foreach (var item in this.ToArray().Reverse())`. I don't think that changes the main idea that `Push`/`Pop` operates on different clones of the stack here. I'll verify that later.

Comment: Of course they do, that's the premise of the question. Both methods `Push` to the same stack, then it's cloned twice (once per `await`). The first `Pop` happens on the first clone (which has 2 items) in the inner method and the second one happens on the second clone which also has 2 items (although it should have only one). That happens because the inner method added to the stack of the outer one as there was no copy because of copy-on-write.

Comment: @i3arnon, I'd say, in the 1st place it's happening because they treat it specially - with deep cloning - for `"System.Diagnostics.Trace.CorrelationManagerSlot"` data slot in `LogicalCallContext.Clone`, unlike with other slots. I imagine they do it to support task forking and multithreading, but it doesn't work anyway.

Comment: No, without deep-cloning only the stack's reference will be cloned and that will lead to multiple threads operating on the same non-thread-safe `Stack` instance. Even when there's only a single thread it still wouldn't work for fork/join scenarios. Deep-cloning is better in this case than shallow-cloning and copy-on-push is better than copy-on-write.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions mentioned here and on the web is to call LogicalSetData on context:

```
CallContext.LogicalSetData("one", null);
Trace.CorrelationManager.StartLogicalOperation();
```

But in fact, just reading current execution context is enough:

```
var context = Thread.CurrentThread.ExecutionContext;
Trace.CorrelationManager.StartLogicalOperation();
```